# What is the nature of action potentials in autonomic nervous system?

Tags: physiology, cardiology, action-potential, autonomic-nervous-system

My conjecture is that the natures of sympathetic and parasympathetic action potentials are different.
My findings propose me that

- sympathetic action potential is little longer lasting than parasympathetic

  - there may be another mechanism in sympathetic action potential - some sort of plateau phase which does not exist in parasympathetic action potential
  - however, I have not managed to gather any convincing evidence on this claim
- parasympathetic action potential has greater energy per one time instance, while the energy of sympathetic AP is distributed along wider time space

My hypothesis is that the **energy of parasympathetic and sympathetic action potentials is equal**.
This would suggest me that the action potentials of the autonomic nervous system are coming from the same source.
Their nature is just different.
**What can this source be exactly?**

I have read the recent Physiology and Pathophysiology books where this topic was not covered rigorously.
I did not manage to find any good publication about the topic, probably, I missed something.

**What is the nature of autonomic nervous system action potentials?**
You can select what ever condition you want and see if you can get some findings as I have got.

Comment: What makes you say the action potentials are different? From my knowledge APs are uniform across all nerves

Comment: See the energy spectrum of APs. You have to define uniform. They seem to have the same energy (uniform; thing which has confused people to think that they are uniform also in nature), but different energy spectrums.